# Scope of all controllers not saving in the service in routing -Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular js. I was trying to save and share the scope of two different controllers.

Below is my script and views.

script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('scope.stored', function (event, data) {
        console.log("scope.stored", data);
    });
});

app.controller('FirstController', function($scope) {
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.add = function(amount) { $scope.counter += amount; };
$scope.subtract = function(amount) { $scope.counter -= amount; };
});


app.config(['$routeProvider',
function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/v1', {
templateUrl: 'views/v1.ejs',
controller: 'controller1'
}).
when('/v2', {
templateUrl: 'views/v2.ejs',
controller: 'controller2'
})

}]);


app.controller('controller1', function($scope,Scopes) {
Scopes.store('controller1',$scope);
$scope.data = "controller1";
$scope.buttonClick = function () {
console.log( Scopes.get('controller2').data);
};
});

app.controller('controller2', function($scope,Scopes) {
Scopes.store('controller2',$scope);
$scope.data = "controller2";
$scope.buttonClick = function () {
console.log( Scopes.get('controller1').data);
};
});



app.factory('Scopes', function ($rootScope) {
    var mem = {};

    return {
        store: function (key, value) {
            $rootScope.$emit('scope.stored', key);
            mem[key] = value;
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return mem[key];
        }
    };
});
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"> </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href='#v1'>View1</a>
    <a href='#v2'>View2</a>
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

v1.ejs:

```
<div ng-controller="controller1">
 {{data}}
 <br>
 <button ng-click="buttonClick()">Clickme!</button>
</div>
```

v2.ejs:

```
<div ng-controller="controller2">
 {{data}}
 <br>
 <button ng-click="buttonClick()">Clickme!</button>
</div>
```

The problem is:

Whenever the page is loaded, #/v1 is triggered.
If i click on 'Clickme', JUST AFTER THE PAGE LOADS, Error: Scopes.get(...) is undefined is fired.

But, if i navigate to #/v2 and then to #/v1, the scopes are getting stored and the error is NOT fired.

Is there is some problem with with routeProvider? All the controllers wont be loaded at on-load event?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Sharing scopes like this is a bad pattern.  If you want to communicate between controllers either: a) Emit and respond to events between them or b) Use a shared service which contains state you want to share.

Comment: To add to Dr Jones, this is because controllers and their scopes in angular are meant to be cleaned up when the aren't needed anymore, whereas services are singletons (if the goal is to pass data you can assign it to a variable or constant service)

Comment: thank  you!  @DrJones

Comment: @AdamCooper86 thank you!